# Entity must be managed to call remove?

Tags: java, jpa

```
public Person deletePerson(Person entity) {
    EntityManager ems = emf.createEntityManager();

    try {
        ems.getTransaction().begin();
        ems.merge(entity);
        ems.remove(entity);
        ems.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        ems.close();
    }
    return entity;
}
```

it doesnt work I don't know why?  Gives me `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: Put yourself in our shoes.  Without any context into what that code is, why would you believe that we can objectively understand not only *where* the error is coming from, and *why* it's occurring?

Comment: its about JPA I am trying to delete a row. Should be simple but I don't know why it doesn't work. The code is standard.

Comment: Your question is very likely to be closed. Don't worry, this isn't the end of the world. As soon as you add the necessary information (by using the edit link just below your post) you can request it to be reopened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because remove operation requires managed entity to be passed to it. You could modify your code like this to make it work:

```
 entity = ems.merge(entity);
 ems.remove(entity);
```

Because [`merge`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge-T-) returns managed entity instance, you can call [`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) with the object it returns, because it is managed by JPA (the object you pass to `merge` is not affected, which is why your code fails).

Comment: You may improve the solution by using em.getReference(). Using ems.merge(entity) will issue unnecessary `SELECT` statement into the DB before `DELETE`. Following should issue only `DELETE` statement:   `ems.remove(ems.getReference(entity.getId))`